# Created simplest module, it installs, nothing happens

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have created a module that works on a vanilla installation of Drupal but doesn't work at all on the corp website that I am working on. Never had this happen before and I have exhausted all I know for whatever typos that could be made. The module only has this as a test:

```
function pathargs_nodapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL ) {
  if($op == 'update') {
    watchdog("debug", "insertings");
  }
}
```

Comment: Do these other sites have caching enabled? Have you tried flushing the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use

```
function pathargs_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL ) {
```

instead of

```
function pathargs_nodapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL ) {
```